# how to get the corresponding values in two data frames and merge them?

Tags: python, dataframe

**I have two data frames.**

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A,'C'], 'ID2':['D','F'], 'No1':[2, 4]})`

**and**

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5'], 'Y':['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5'], 'No2':[ 1,2,3,4,5]})`

The values in column `No1` in `df1` are always among the values of `No2` in `df2`.

I want to create a **new data frame** that extracts the corresponding X and Y from df2 such as:

```
df_new = [['A', 'D', 2, 'X2', 'Y2']
          ['C', 'F', 4, 'X4', 'Y4']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `pd.merge()` to merge the two data frames based on the common columns `No1` from `df1` and `No2` from `df2`.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='No1', right_on='No2')
df_new = merged_df[['ID1', 'ID2', 'No1', 'X', 'Y']]
```

Output:

> ```
> >> df_new
>   ID1 ID2  No1   X   Y
> 0   A   D    2  X2  Y2
> 1   B   E    3  X3  Y3
> 2   C   F    4  X4  Y4
> ```

---

ADDED

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': ['A', 'C'], 'ID2': ['D', 'F'], 'No1': [2, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'], 'Y': ['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4', 'Y5'], 'No2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='No1', right_on='No2')
df_new = merged_df[['ID1', 'ID2', 'No1', 'X', 'Y']]
```

Output:

> ```
> df_new
> >   ID1 ID2  No1   X   Y
> 0   A   D    2  X2  Y2
> 1   C   F    4  X4  Y4
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just dont understand do I need the second line?

Comment: The second line is just used to select only needed columns (drop `No2`).

Comment: there is something wrong with this code. In the main datasets that I have, only the first row of the merged dataset is right. and for the rest of the rows, the corresponding X and Y are wrong.

Comment: That means the examples in your question don't cover all cases. Please give more examples to sufficiently represent your entire dataset.

Comment: I edited the example I provided. Now, the values for `No1` are not in order.

Comment: For your new example, my code still works for me. See my added answer.

Comment: Thanks, Does this method shuffle or sort the new dataset based on any columns?

Comment: By default, it doesn't. If you want to sort the result based on the join keys, you can set `sort=True` explicitly in the function.